# Taking derivatives at potential singularities of multivariable rational functions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I have a rational function $f=p/q: \mathbb{C}^n\to\mathbb{C}$, and I know that the polynomials $p,q$ share a single root, say at $x$. I'm wondering when the gradient of $f$ is well defined at $x$. I know that in single-variable complex analysis (and well, many other places) there is a notion of a "removable singularity," and if the singularity is removable then the function can be made to be defined and holomorphic at the point of the original singularity. In this case, it's a bit different, because $p,q$ correspond to two varieties that intersect at $x$, but the varieties are not actually the same, so I'm not exactly sure if there is any notion of a removable singularity here. Ultimately I'm interested in whether there's a well defined derivative at $x$ (and if there are particular conditions $p,q$ would need to satisfy for this to exist, just like in the single-variable case, like when they vanish with the same order).